# Apiman does not restore gateway

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, ibm-api-management, apiman

Could you please assist me with the following issue.
I use Apiman version 1.2.1

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:9.0.2.Final
ENV APIMAN_VERSION 1.2.1.Final
```

I expose this version via kubernetes, as a persistent volume I use postgres in the same container. Once I create it at the first time, after this in the apiman I have added Organization/ API/.... and all necessary staff.

I press on button to publish api, and may check that it works perfect, so I use `kubectl port-forward pod-name 8080:8080` and may check my gateway via browser `http:localhost:8080/apiman-gateway/ORgId/bla/bla/bla/bla?givemedescriptionbyid=1`.

After this one I go to console and kill apiman pod, as a result of pod restart, the same operation `kubectl port-forward new-pod-name 8080:8080`, and I can see that the all data of apiman like organization, apis and all other staff is already there.

But one big problem if you try to call gateway again, it tells you that:

> {"responseCode":500,"message":"API not
>   found.","trace":"io.apiman.gateway.engine.beans.exceptions.InvalidApiException:
>   API not found.\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.engine.impl.ApiRequestExecutorImpl$3.handle(ApiRequestExecutorImpl.java:278)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.engine.impl.ApiRequestExecutorImpl$3.handle(ApiRequestExecutorImpl.java:271)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.engine.impl.SecureRegistryWrapper$1.handle(SecureRegistryWrapper.java:122)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.engine.impl.SecureRegistryWrapper$1.handle(SecureRegistryWrapper.java:111)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.engine.es.CachingESRegistry.getApi(CachingESRegistry.java:116)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.engine.impl.SecureRegistryWrapper.getApi(SecureRegistryWrapper.java:111)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.engine.impl.ApiRequestExecutorImpl.execute(ApiRequestExecutorImpl.java:270)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.platforms.servlet.GatewayServlet.doAction(GatewayServlet.java:232)\n\tat
>   io.apiman.gateway.platforms.servlet.GatewayServlet.doGet(GatewayServlet.java:77)\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)\n\tat
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)\n\tat
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)\n\tat
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n"}

I can see, that by metrics of calls in api manager, all my calls can reach apiman-gateway, but I get 500 response code.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody will met such error, so, I have solved it with the following steps, first of all we need to use only new version of APIMAN, list of fixes already implemented. And also apiman-gateway cannot live without elastic search to restore itself. Hence elasticsearch configuration should to be provided.